# Element width decreasing in one direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I ran into situation earlier where I have a position relative container with a position absolute element inside. The element inside contains an image that has a max width of 100%. If I move this element which I have called "item" in the fiddle below using "left" the width of the element decreases the further I go to the right (does not happen if moving to the left with negative values). This happens the opposite way if use the css rule "right". If I take the width declaration off the image this no longer occurs. Does anyone know why this is the case. Here is a fiddle I created to show the issue.

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom:32%;
} 

.item {
  position:absolute;
}

.content {
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;

}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}


<div class="content">
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "item">
    <a href='https://postimg.org/image/h3h0e82rx/' target='_blank'><img src='https://s22.postimg.org/kabjxun81/banner.jpg' border='0' alt='banner'/><br /><a target='_blank' href='https://postimage.org/'></a><br /><br />
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rv9wcqh2/

An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Percentage based widths, according to the W3C, "[refer to width of containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-width-property)." When you offset the child element (`.item`), it bases its percentage width on the *remaining* space within its [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details). Again, according to the spec:

> Note: For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a block container element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the *padding box* of that element. This is a change from CSS1, where the percentage width was always calculated with respect to the *content box* of the parent element.

Two tests to visualize this.

**1:** Remove the `left:N` on `.item` and instead add `padding-left` to one of the container elements. Will have the same effect (presuming you've set `box-sizing: border-box` on the container, otherwise the whole thing will grow).
**1a:** Double down. `padding-left: 100px` on the container and `left: 100px` on `.item`. Image will continue to fill 100% of the *remaining* space (now very small).
**2:** Use a px width on the image. This will keep the image the same size as the original, moved over by `left: Npx`. Since you have `overflow: hidden` on the parent, the right side of the image will be truncated by the containing block's right edge.

**Edit for comment:**

> Unfortunately I'm struggling to understand why this decrease in width doesn't happen if I use negative values. i.e left -50% moves it to the left and item maintains it dimensions. right - 50% moves it to the right and it also keeps it's dimensions.

Yeah, it's a little odd but `left: -50%`, when the containing block is 400px, means the targeted element now has 600px from its left edge to the right edge of the containing block. Still, the percentage based `max-width` value on the targeted element remains relative to the containing block's computed width. So `max-width: 100%` on an element inside of a containing block that is set to `width: 400px` will never exceed 400px. Since it now has 600px to 'work with', it grows to its max width of 400px.

Comment: Hi Will, cheers for taking a look at this. Unfortunately I'm struggling to understand why this decrease in width doesn't happen if I use negative values. i.e left -50% moves it to the left and item maintains it dimensions. right - 50% moves it to the right and it also keeps it's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired behaviour setting a width of 100% to element

The positive values for the left and right properties constrain the width, but negative ones don't.

As a side note, your  elements in the fiddle are miss matched

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom:32%;
} 

.item {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;  /* added */
}

.content {
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
  
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "item">
  <a href='https://postimg.org/image/h3h0e82rx/' target='_blank'><img src='https://s22.postimg.org/kabjxun81/banner.jpg' border='0' alt='banner'/></a>
  <br />
  <a target='_blank' href='https://postimage.org/'></a><br><br>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers vals, I had already managed to fix this previously. It was more of an issue that I didn't understand why it was behaving this way which was why I asked. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you could use the css for `clip-path`. Is this in essence what you're looking for?

```css
body {background:rgba(255,255,255,1);}

.container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom:32%;
} 

.item {
  position:absolute;
}

.content {
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 50%);

}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "item">
    <a href='https://postimg.org/image/h3h0e82rx/' target='_blank'><img src='https://s22.postimg.org/kabjxun81/banner.jpg' border='0' alt='banner'/><br /><a target='_blank' href='https://postimage.org/'></a><br /><br />
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that isn't what I meant. I'm trying to keep the element item the same size even when moving it to the left using left however the width decreases. Thanks for looking though